# Is it possible to use Lucene .NET search library to build cross platform application?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I want to create a search library and I use that library in all of my clients that runs across all platforms (Linux, windows, MAC, Xamarin). Lucene.Net library supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** Now that Lucene.Net 4.8.0 supports [.NET Standard 1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), you can use it on Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Andriod, and .NET Core.

Lucene.NET 3.0.3 and lower versions only support Windows, since they are available on .NET Framework only.